# Java generic method erasure order

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use Java 1.6u32.
In legacy code I have method:

```
static <T> T lookup(Class<? super T> interfaceClass){...}
```

There are three kinds of usages of it:

```
ConcreteX x = lookup(InterfaceX.class);
InterfaceX x = lookup(InterfaceX.class);
lookup(InterfaceX.class).someMethodOfInterfaceX();
```

The problem is that the third one compiles when I use some ant build script, but it fails when I build project in Intellij Idea.
Error message is:

```
... cannot find symbol:
symbol: method someMethodOfInterfaceX()
location: class java.lang.Object
```

When I cast explicitly to InterfaceX then IDEA build succeeds:

```
((InterfaceX)lookup(InterfaceX.class)).someMethodOfInterfaceX();
```

Is code wrong and should not compile by ant or is something wrong with IDEA compiler?

EDIT: - classes used to reproduce error:

```
public class ErasureProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImplementationX n = lookup(InterfaceX.class);
        lookup(InterfaceX.class).m();
    }

    static <T extends Object> T lookup(Class<? super T> cls){
        return null;
    }
}

public class ImplementationX implements InterfaceX {
    @Override
    public Integer m() {
        return 0;
    }
}

public interface InterfaceX {
    Integer m();
}
```

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using as I have no issue compiling similar Generic trickery from IntelliJ myself. (Both with IntelliJ using the Eclipse compiler or the JavaC back-end)

Comment: Yeah, this looks like an IntelliJ bug.

Comment: Btw. how does the `lookup` method know, that it has to return an instance of `ConcreteX`? Looks to me like a questionable design that breaks as soon as there is more than one interface implementation.

Comment: Intellij 12.1.4 on JVM 1.7.0_17.

IMHO design is wrong. Yes, it should fail when there is more then one implementation. But that is clear. Compiler behaviour is the interesting problem here.